# Need help understanding this method

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-types

I came across this old code in the process of adding java generics and I do not understand what is going on here and what needs to be changed.

```
static void sortByDate( List list)   throws Exception
{  
    class MyComparator implements Comparator {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            RQEntry  o11 = (RQEntry) o1;
            RQEntry  o22 = (RQEntry) o2;

            int cc = ((String)o11.getHandledDate() ).compareTo(o22.getHandledDate() );

            return (cc < 0 ? -1 : cc > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
}
```

**Question 1**: Could someone explain how this method performs comparison?

**Question 2**: What generic type parameters should be passed to comply with Java 5 standards?

**Question 3**: How is `compare` method called just by creating a new instance of `MyComparator`?

*Update:*

Just found this link which finally helped me understand this code: http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

Comment: read the java doc of comparator. this will explain alot

Comment: Right, and read the javadoc for `Collections.sort`.

Comment: What does `o22.getHandledDate()` return? If it doesn't return `String`, then the code shouldn't compile. And if it returns `String`, and the method name is a bit inappropriate.

Comment: Why does a return type of `String` necessary make the method name inappropriate? It certainly seems to be sorting (alphabetically) by "Handled date".

Comment: It's a personal choice though, but IMO, `getHandledDate` should really return a `Date`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List<RQEntry>` you can sort it now using this comparator.
The `RQEntry` objects will be compared based on their handled dates.

This is what this call here is doing.

`Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());`

Behind the scenes, when the sort algorithm needs to compare
two RQEntry objects, it will call the `compare` method of your
comparator. That's all.

Comment: What happens when `new MyComparator()` is called? Is the `compare` method called automatically? This class has no default constructor.

Comment: An instance is created and passed to the sort method. Read the javadoc for `sort`.

Comment: Each class has implicit default constructor if you define no constructors. No worries about this.

Comment: So the `compare` method is called just by creating a new instance of `MyComparator`? How?

Comment: No, no. It is called when you call `sort`. And it's not called just once but each time the `sort` needs to compare two objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** It is doing a string comparison between whatever is returned from the getHandleDate method. I have no idea why it is doing:

```
return (cc < 0 ? -1 : cc > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

since cc should by all rights be -1, 0 or 1. The code could just as easily do:

```
return ((String)o11.getHandledDate()).compareTo(o22.getHandledDate());
```

**Answer 2:** You could use generics to simplify as follows:

```
static void sortByDate(List<RQEntry> list)   throws Exception
{  
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<RQEntry> {
        public int compare(RQEntry o1, RQEntry o2) {
            return ((String)o1.getHandledDate()).compareTo(o2.getHandledDate());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I also need to override `equals` for `MyComparator`?

Answer (score 1):

This code allows you to sort a `List` by date. It makes an assumption that the `List` is actually a `List<RQEntry>`.

Java allows you to call `Collections.sort(list, new SomeComparator())`. The comparator you specify in the second argument contains the code that decides how to order items in the list.

The actual comparison interface is that you need to implement `int compare(Object o1, Object o2)`. According to the specification, you need to return `0` if the two objects are the same, a negative value if the first item is ordered before the second item, and a positive value if the second item is ordered before the first.

As an example, if you had a list containing `[37, 19]` then calling `compare(37, 19)` would return `1` (assuming you want to sort a list of integers in ascending order).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain how is `compare` method called just by creating a new instance of `MyComparator`?

Comment: @Prince that's how the `Collections.sort` method works. It requires a `Comparator`, which is an interface that guarantees the presence of a `compare(o1, o2)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Question 1: Could someone explain how this method performs comparison?
```

For each object the `getHandledDate()` method is called and the return values (obviously `String`s) are compared (default comparison is lexicograhical ordering.

The tricky part is understanding the return value of the `String.compareTo` method used. It is defined in the [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
Question 2: What generic type parameters should be passed to comply with Java 5 standards?
```

The generic type should obviously be `RQEntry`. -> `class MyComparator implements Comparator<RQEntry>`.

See also:

- [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: "String.compareTo method used. It is defined in the Comparable interface." - It is not defined in Comparable interface but it is a method of String class.

Comment: @Prince Yes and no. Of course the exact return value of the function is defined in the String class. But String is implementing the interface Comparable, which says this about the method: `Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.`